# The function $F(y)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(2xy)dx$ (Lebesgue) satisfies $F'(y)+2yF(y)=0.$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that the function defined as the Lebesgue Integral $$F(y)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(2xy)dx$$
satisfies $F'(y)+2yF(y)=0$, and after that, that $F(y)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}e^{-y^2}$.
I tried this:

---

First, we have that $F'(y)=\int_0^\infty -2xe^{-x^2}\sin (2xy)dx$, and that

$$F'(y)+2yF(y)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}(2y \cos(2xy)-2x\sin(2xy))dx.$$

So I want to prove that this last integral is 0. I suppose I should use in some step that
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll kick yourself: the integrand of $F'(y)+2yF(y)$ is the derivative with respect to $x$ of
$$ e^{-x^2}\sin{2xy}, $$
which vanishes at the endpoints. Hence the integral is zero.

Comment: I'll kick myself, then. I didn't expect that.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Integrate by parts the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}2y\cos(2xy)\,dx$ with $u=e^{-x^2}$ and $v=\sin(2xy)$.

Answer (score 1):

As Chappers said:
\begin{aligned}
F^{\prime}(y)+2 y F(y) & =\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2}(2 y \cos (2 x y)-2 x \sin (x x y) d) \\
& =\left[e^{-x^2} \sin (2 x y)\right]_0^{\infty}\\&=0
\end{aligned}
which is a separable linear differential equation.
$$
\begin{aligned}
F^{\prime}(y) & =-2 y F(y) \\
\frac{d F(y)}{F(y)} & =-2 y d y \\
\int \frac{d F(y)}{F(y)} & =-\int 2 y d y \\
\ln (F(y)) & =-y^2+C \\
F(y) & =F(0) e^{-y^2} \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-y^2}
\end{aligned}
$$